# Review option for Stack Overflow mobile application

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, triage

These days I am becoming a little addicted to Stack Overflow, so even when I am not in front of my computer I keep surfing through questions and answers all the day using my mobile phone (the Android Stack Overflow app) which many users of Stack Overflow do. Once back to my computer I try to help by handling some reviews.

The point is, that I can (I guess many of you too) make much more reviews, specially those which doesn't need modifications (like for Triage) just by using my phone application if the review option exist.

So, is Stack Overflow planning to add that kind of options to the mobile app or that's not so nessecary?

**NB:** I know that -at least- for me, the limit of reviews per queue per day is 20, but if I can handle that during the day (on my way to work, working breaks ...) that will give me more time in the evening to contribute in other ways (answering, flagging, editing ....)

Comment: Highly doubt it - the REST API doesn't have any methods for dealing with reviews, and with good reason.

Comment: I'm addicted too. Many times I get myself using my phone to review posts through the website choosing the desktop version.

Comment: @BoltClock a malicious user only needs a few hours to replicate the review queue page's behavior in his script and start (literally) robo-reviewing, so I'm not sure if that's really a "good reason".

Comment: @AndréDaniel It's not about opening up the possibility, but about making it *so much easier*. The API also allows you to quickly link to a user without actually needing their login credentials, which also opens the door to users "giving away" their reviews to other users who want to use them via third-party tools. Just let any user go click a button "Allow use of my reviews" and anybody can go use *someone else's* account to perform reviews. That's extremely difficult to achieve without an API, but a snap to achieve with an API.

Comment: @animuson stop thinking that not having an API is what's preventing abuse of the reviews currently. What's really preventing automated abuse is the same thing that prevents someone from just clicking their way through all reviews manually (ie. review bans, audits and the fact that accounts are valuable and no one wants an account-wide ban for repeated abuse). An API will still have these same restrictions and nothing will change. By the way, that makes me think about Snapchat and their pointless war against third-party clients in hopes of increasing their user's security...

Comment: @AndréDaniel I'm not even talking about automated abuse or the prevention of it, but about allowing users to full-out bypass the review limits by using other willing accounts. Users have already expressed their desire via feature requests to "delegate" their reviews to others when they don't want to use them. Imagine someone who builds a site and implements their own review system where any user can store an access key and let anyone go review using their limit because "well, they want to." That's not something we want to happen.

Comment: @animuson I understand your concerns but I'm afraid what you're saying is already possible (just build a website like you say, but instead of storing OAuth tokens just store SE OpenID passwords), and the reason nobody does that is because people are concerned giving someone else read+write access to their account. Whether it's their password or the oauth token doesn't make much difference IMO. But that account-sharing problem can be solved by requiring more than OAuth for that particular API endpoint (like the actual SE openid password).

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but this is something I've been thinking recently too. Having started to get more addicted to SO I have started using the phone version. It's been two years, is this feature any more likely to happen?

Comment: Would be very nice feature. I've been waiting to see this happen, even it would be a lot better if we could have more mobile friendly web browser views for reviewing if app option is causing too much trouble.