# Mobile Access to Review Queues

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, mobile-web

It's not easy to use Stack Overflow from a mobile device for obvious reasons (harder to type, research, etc.), but one thing that would be easy to do on a phone is to participate in a review queue. However, if there is a way to do that currently, I can't seem to find it.

On the other hand, users participating in a review queue by phone might provide lower quality feedback and so we might want to discourage phone reviews.

So, my question: Is there a way to participate in a review queue by phone, and if not, should there be?

Comment: Dup: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286046/review-option-for-stack-overflow-mobile-application?

Comment: Make it like Tinder ! Swipe left - nope, Swipe right - Looks OK. Double the fun !

Comment: There you go, it's added just a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 8):

You can access the review queue using the regular url: https://stackoverflow.com/review.

The 'experience' on mobile devices isn't very good so reviewing is quite hard to do. I am not sure if that is an important issue to fix, I don't think this should be a concern of the development team now. It 'works' and I am unsure how much reviewers will participate due to this feature.